# mysql / bitmask: select for NOT value

Tags: mysql, bit-masks

I have a table with a bitmask column(unsigned int). This field has values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

How do I select for NOT a specific value? IE I don't care what the other bits are - only that a specific bit be 0.

What I've tried:

> select count(*) from mytable;

This gives me **3387255**.

> select count(*) from mytable where outageMask & ~8;

This gives me **552061**.

So I would assume that:

> select count(*) from mytable where outageMask & 8;

would give me **2835194**. Not so. Instead I get **87711**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the column have `NULL` values?

Comment: No NULLs. 0 would represent 'no data'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> only that a specific bit be 0.

This is important. Let's see, what you calculated (with 8 bit numbers for simplification):

```
 8 = 0b00001000
~8 = 0b11110111
```

So, what do these bitmasks test if you BITWISE AND them with another value? The first mask tests if bit "8" is set. The second mask tests if **all other bits** are set. But this is not what you intended, you wanted a negation of the whole statement. Which is easy:

```
select count(*) from mytable where (outageMask & 8) = 0;
```